# I call a function in itself recursively, but it doesn't seem to be working

Tags: php, recursion, web-crawler

I am calling a crawl() function recursively that gets the content of a page and echo's it.
It works when I manually call it from outside the function, but when I recursively call it from inside the function I get no output from the recursive calls. The only output I get is from the one manual call.

Why isn't this working, what am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ERROR );

define( "CRAWL_LIMIT_PER_DOMAIN", 50 );

$domains = array();

$urls = array();

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$matches = array();

function crawl( $domObject, $url, $matchList )
{
    global $domains, $urls;
    $parse = parse_url( $url );
    $domains[ $parse['host'] ]++;
    $urls[] = $url;

    $content = file_get_contents( $url );
    if ( $content === FALSE ){
        return;
    } 
    echo  strip_tags($content) . "<br /><br /><br />";
        array_push($matchList, 'http://www.the-irf.com/hello/hello5.html');
        array_push($matchList, 'http://www.the-irf.com/hello/hello6.html');
        array_push($matchList, 'http://www.the-irf.com/hello/end.html');


    foreach( $matchList[0] as $crawled_url ) {
        $parse = parse_url( $crawled_url );
        if ( count( $domains[ $parse['host'] ] ) < CRAWL_LIMIT_PER_DOMAIN && !in_array( $crawled_url, $urls ) ) {
            sleep( 1 );
            crawl( $domObject, $crawled_url, $matchList );
        }
    }
}

crawl($dom, 'http://the-irf.com/hello/hello6.html', $matches);
?>
```

Comment: Because $content === FALSE?

Comment: I don't understand why you're are setting matchlist values and then doing foreach( $matchList[0] as $crawled_url ) { inside your recursive function. What are you trying to accomplish? If you are getting webpage content, why not use curl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies when you are using your foreach.

```
foreach($matchList[0] as $crawled_url){
```

Your array `$matchList` looks like: `array('http://www.the-irf.com/hello/hello5.html', 'http://www.the-irf.com/hello/hello6.html', 'http://www.the-irf.com/hello/end.html')`.

`foreach` is expecting the first parameter to be an array. `$matchList[0]` is not an array but the string `'http://www.the-irf.com/hello/hello5.html'`.

In other words, if you change that line to

```
foreach($matchList as $crawled_url){
```

you will start calling the function recursively.

Comment: That makes complete sense. The syntax I was using in the foreach is for 2-d arrays. I don't even know why I did that. I must have originally planned #matchList to be an array at some point. Thank you for your help!